# SimpleITK Python apply BinaryMorphologicalClosingImageFilter to a TIFF image

Tags: python, filter, simpleitk

I am trying to apply a BinaryMorphologicalClosingImageFilter to a binary TIFF image to fill empty spaces between structures (where ImageJ Fill Holes doesn't help). Here is the code I use:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

#Import TIFF image
image = sitk.ReadImage("C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/Desktop/STL/4_bina.tif")

#Apply Filter
sitk.BinaryMorphologicalClosingImageFilter()

#Export Image
sitk.WriteImage(image, "C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/Desktop/STL/4_bina_itk.tif")
```

The code runs without an error but the problem is that I can't figure out how to set the Kernel Size of the filter and the image doesn't experience a change. Any advise?
(I got the idea to use this filter from the following post on SO: [Fill holes on a 3D image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706501/fill-holes-on-a-3d-image))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created the BinaryMorphologicalClosingImageFilter object, but you haven't actually applied it to your input image.  Your code should be something like this:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

#Import TIFF image
image = sitk.ReadImage("C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/Desktop/STL/4_bina.tif")

#Apply Filter
filter = sitk.BinaryMorphologicalClosingImageFilter()
filter.SetKernelRadius([2, 2])
output_image = filter.Execute(image)


#Export Image
sitk.WriteImage(output_image, "C:/Users/Christian Nikolov/Desktop/STL/4_bina_itk.tif")
```

I set the kernel size to [2, 2], but you can use whatever unsigned integer size works best for you.